# Eclipse Mars gets stuck at Maven project import

Tags: eclipse, maven, import

I'm trying to create a new workspace in my local Eclipse Mars using an existing Maven Project. Problem is, after importing it, I can't modify it in any way thanks to Eclipse not completing the action "Importing Maven projects", which hangs at 40% forever:

[image]

This seems to block me from saving anything new to the code. Any way I can get around this? Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**

So thanks to [greg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2670892/greg-449) I was reminded of the project's .metadata directory, and inside the .log file, this came up at the end:

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.oomph.setup.core 2 0 2019-12-10 16:28:18.763
!MESSAGE Proxy Authentication Required
!STACK 0
org.eclipse.oomph.util.IOExceptionWithCause: Proxy Authentication Required
    at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.core.util.ECFURIHandlerImpl.createInputStream(ECFURIHandlerImpl.java:295)
    at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.resource.impl.ExtensibleURIConverterImpl.createInputStream(ExtensibleURIConverterImpl.java:360)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.core.util.SetupCoreUtil.handleArchiveRedirection(SetupCoreUtil.java:383)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.core.util.SetupCoreUtil.configureResourceSet(SetupCoreUtil.java:365)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.core.util.SetupCoreUtil.createResourceSet(SetupCoreUtil.java:133)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.core.SetupContext.associate(SetupContext.java:359)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.core.SetupContext.createSelf(SetupContext.java:238)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.ui.SetupUIPlugin.performStartup(SetupUIPlugin.java:563)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.ui.SetupUIPlugin.access$3(SetupUIPlugin.java:346)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.ui.SetupUIPlugin$1$1.run(SetupUIPlugin.java:243)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:55)
Caused by: org.eclipse.ecf.filetransfer.IncomingFileTransferException: Proxy Authentication Required
    at org.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.httpclient4.HttpClientRetrieveFileTransfer.openStreams(HttpClientRetrieveFileTransfer.java:658)
    at org.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.retrieve.AbstractRetrieveFileTransfer.sendRetrieveRequest(AbstractRetrieveFileTransfer.java:885)
    at org.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.retrieve.AbstractRetrieveFileTransfer.sendRetrieveRequest(AbstractRetrieveFileTransfer.java:576)
    at org.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.retrieve.MultiProtocolRetrieveAdapter.sendRetrieveRequest(MultiProtocolRetrieveAdapter.java:106)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.core.util.ECFURIHandlerImpl.createInputStream(ECFURIHandlerImpl.java:232)
    ... 10 more

!ENTRY org.eclipse.m2e.logback.appender 2 0 2019-12-10 16:28:48.305
!MESSAGE Failure to transfer com.alexnederlof:jasperreports-plugin/maven-metadata.xml from https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer metadata com.alexnederlof:jasperreports-plugin/maven-metadata.xml from/to central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2): Not authorized by proxy, ReasonPhrase:Proxy Authentication Required.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.m2e.logback.appender 2 0 2019-12-10 16:28:48.329
!MESSAGE Failure to transfer com.alexnederlof:jasperreports-plugin/maven-metadata.xml from https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer metadata com.alexnederlof:jasperreports-plugin/maven-metadata.xml from/to central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2): Not authorized by proxy, ReasonPhrase:Proxy Authentication Required.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.m2e.logback.appender 2 0 2019-12-10 16:28:48.352
!MESSAGE Failure to transfer com.alexnederlof:jasperreports-plugin/maven-metadata.xml from https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer metadata com.alexnederlof:jasperreports-plugin/maven-metadata.xml from/to central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2): Not authorized by proxy, ReasonPhrase:Proxy Authentication Required.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.m2e.logback.appender 2 0 2019-12-10 16:28:48.585
!MESSAGE Failure to transfer com.alexnederlof:jasperreports-plugin/maven-metadata.xml from https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer metadata com.alexnederlof:jasperreports-plugin/maven-metadata.xml from/to central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2): Not authorized by proxy, ReasonPhrase:Proxy Authentication Required.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.m2e.logback.appender 2 0 2019-12-10 16:28:48.634
!MESSAGE Failure to transfer com.alexnederlof:jasperreports-plugin/maven-metadata.xml from https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer metadata com.alexnederlof:jasperreports-plugin/maven-metadata.xml from/to central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2): Not authorized by proxy, ReasonPhrase:Proxy Authentication Required.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.m2e.logback.appender 2 0 2019-12-10 16:28:48.675
!MESSAGE Failure to transfer com.alexnederlof:jasperreports-plugin/maven-metadata.xml from https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer metadata com.alexnederlof:jasperreports-plugin/maven-metadata.xml from/to central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2): Not authorized by proxy, ReasonPhrase:Proxy Authentication Required.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.m2e.logback.appender 2 0 2019-12-10 16:28:50.840
!MESSAGE Failure to transfer com.alexnederlof:jasperreports-plugin/maven-metadata.xml from https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer metadata com.alexnederlof:jasperreports-plugin/maven-metadata.xml from/to central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2): Not authorized by proxy, ReasonPhrase:Proxy Authentication Required.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.m2e.logback.appender 2 0 2019-12-10 16:28:50.870
!MESSAGE Failure to transfer com.alexnederlof:jasperreports-plugin/maven-metadata.xml from https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer metadata com.alexnederlof:jasperreports-plugin/maven-metadata.xml from/to central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2): Not authorized by proxy, ReasonPhrase:Proxy Authentication Required.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.m2e.logback.appender 2 0 2019-12-10 16:28:50.893
!MESSAGE Failure to transfer com.alexnederlof:jasperreports-plugin/maven-metadata.xml from https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer metadata com.alexnederlof:jasperreports-plugin/maven-metadata.xml from/to central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2): Not authorized by proxy, ReasonPhrase:Proxy Authentication Required.
```

I was aware that proxy authentication blocked me from downloading new plugins for Eclipse, but didn't know it could disallow me to import an existing project in some cases. For other projects it works fine. Anyway, I'll see if I can sort this out with my network admin and come back here later.

Comment: Eclipse is 4 years and 8 releases old, maybe using an up to date Eclipse would help. Otherwise look in the .log file in the workspace .metadata directory to see if there is an error message.

Comment: Thanks for the info on the .metadata directory. Kind of a newbie at Eclipse..

Comment: Can you reproduce this issue with Eclipse 2019-09 (4.13) instead of Eclipse Mars which is outdated for several years now? If yes, please show the log starting with `!SESSION` formatted as code snippet (instead of as quote) to prevent line breaks.

Comment: I strongly recommend to build your project the first time on plain command line cause it's simply much faster...

Comment: @howlger Sadly, I can't. My company only provides some older versions at the moment, thanks to strict policies regarding software installs. If not for that, I'd probably be using the latest version. But as I said in the edit, I'm still working on getting the proper proxy privileges, as I get the same error message referring to "proxy authentication required" whenever I attempt to access the Eclipse Marketplace. I'll update the post whenever it gets done.

Comment: @howlger There is no FUD it's simply faster than in Eclipse can be simply being measured...

Comment: If the proxy access is not working this can be the issue...cause that blocks download s of artifacts. The other question is: Do you have corporate repository manager ?

Comment: Well, using outdated software is risky for other reasons, too. It is the policy that leads to such problems, so you should ask the people responsible for this policy for a solution. With this policy, how you can use Maven with a non-local repository? If a `.project` file exists, you could try importing the project as an existing Eclipse project. Otherwise, I don't know.

Comment: @khmarbaise Do you have reproducible numbers? How does Eclipse slow down the execution of a Maven build? How is this even possible due the fact that Maven is running in a separate process?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, my mistake. Turns out that something was missing, and it was the settings.xml file that should be present inside C:\Users\.m2. After taking care of that, the import finished succesfully. Thanks for the attention, guys.